# Get foreign key in external content type to show up in list view

Tags: sharepoint, content-type, sharepoint-2010

I have come across blogs about how to setup an external content type (e.g. http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/02/02/it-s-easy-to-configure-an-external-list-with-business-connectivity-services-bcs-in-sharepoint-foundation-2010.aspx) but I have not seen any examples of what to do when your external SQL DB has foreign keys.

For example.  I have a database that has orders and customers.  An order has one and only one customer and a customer can have many orders.  How can I setup external content types in such a way that when in the list view of these external content types, I can jump between and possible lookup values to that other type?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the **one-to-many or master-detail association** between the *Customers* and *Orders* tables in sharepoint designer. These Links will help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394528(v=office.14).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558417(v=office.14).aspx

I've tested that. My case was to use the sharepoint search to search for projects' attachments at external system. I had two tables *Projects* and *Attachments* with one-to-many relationship. I made two ECT for each of them with the association operation on the *Attachments* ECT.

Answer (score -1):

I have written this blog post which shows how to do what you are after:

In Visual Studio

http://www.lightningtools.com/blog/archive/2011/01/10/sharepoint-external-listndash-using-the-picker-for-foreign-keys.aspx

In SharePoint Designer

http://lightningtools.com/blog/archive/2010/06/14/lookup-foreign-key-values-in-external-lists.aspx

Hope these help